# Reverse Geocoding With Dynamic Form

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I've been trying to find a way to use the 'Reverse Geocoding' service with the Latitude and Longitude co-ordinates coming from two text boxes on my HTML form, and I must admit I'm not really sure what I need to do.

I have managed to do this with the 'Geocode' service (see code below), but I just wondered whether someone may be able to point me in the right direction of how I could adapt the 'Geocode' javascript I have to the 'Reverse Geocoging' service.

```js
(function Geocode() {

    // This is defining the global variables
    var map, geocoder, myMarker;

    window.onload = function() {

        //This is creating the map with the desired options
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.378051,-3.435973),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

        // This is making the link with the 'Search For Location' HTML form
        var form = document.getElementById('SearchForLocationForm');

        // This is catching the forms submit event
        form.onsubmit = function() {

            // This is getting the Address from the HTML forms 'Address' text box
            var address = document.getElementById('GeocodeAddress').value;

            // This is making the Geocoder call
            getCoordinates(address);

            // This is preventing the form from doing a page submit
            return false;
        }
    }

    // This creates the function that will return the coordinates for the address
    function getCoordinates(address) {

        // This checks to see if there is already a geocoded object. If not, it creates one
        if(!geocoder) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }

        // This is creating a GeocoderRequest object
        var geocoderRequest = {
            address: address
        }

        // This is making the Geocode request
        geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {

            // This checks to see if the Status is 'OK 'before proceeding
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                // This centres the map on the returned location
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                // This creates a new marker and adds it to the map
                var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    zoom: 12,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    draggable:true
                });

                //This fills out the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' text boxes on the HTML form
                document.getElementById('Latitude').value=  results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                document.getElementById('Longitude').value=  results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                //This allows the marker to be draggable and tells the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' text boxes on the HTML form to update with the new co-ordinates as the marker is dragged
                google.maps.event.addListener(     
                    myMarker,     
                    'dragend',     
                    function() {         
                        document.getElementById('Latitude').value = myMarker.position.lat();         
                        document.getElementById('Longitude').value = myMarker.position.lng(); 

                        var point = myMarker.getPosition();
                        map.panTo(point);   
                    } 
                ); 
            }
        } 
        )
    }
})();
```

UPDATE

Firstly, many thanks for the code you kindly posted and the suggestion to go and have a look at the Google documentation.

From what you suggested, and from what I took from the additional documentation I came up with the following. However, when I click my submit button nothing happens, almost as if there is no command attached to it. I don't receive any error messages and I've checked to make sure that I've linked the code to the correct fieldnames and all seems ok. I just wondered whether it would be at all possible if you, or indeed anyone else, could take a look at it please to tell me where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

```js
(function ReverseGeocode() {

    var form, geocoderRequest, latlng, myMarker, point;

    window.onload = function() {

        //This is creating the map with the desired options
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.378051,-3.435973),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('Latitude', 'Longitude');

        // This is making the Geocode request
        geocoder.geocode({'LatLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {  

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                    
                if (results[1]) {           
                    map.setZoom(11);          
                    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({               
                        position: results[0].geometry.location, 
                        map: map  
                    });
                    //This fills out the 'Address' text boxe on the HTML form
                    document.getElementById('Address').value=  results[0].geometry.location.latlng();

                    var point = myMarker.getPosition();
                    map.panTo(point);   
                } 
            }
        }
)}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the latitude and longitude from your form, you do something like this (using your above code as a starting point, for the sake of clarity):

```js
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeFromForm,longitudeFromForm);

// This is creating a GeocoderRequest object
var geocoderRequest = {
    'latlng':latlng
}

// This is making the Geocode request
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {

// This checks to see if the Status is 'OK 'before proceeding
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // Do stuff with the result here
}
```

If you haven't read it yet, you may want to read the Reverse Geocoding section of http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. I've come up with some revised code but I must admit, being new to this site, I'm not sure how to post a reply beyond the 'Character Count' set in the 'Add Comments' section. You could perhaps advise if there is a way to get around this? Many thanks and regards.

Comment: If your revised code still has problems that you are trying to solve, edit your original question and insert the new code at the bottom with a note explaining that it's an update and what the remaining problem is.  If your code is a solution, post it as an answer.  If my answer (or someone else's answer) solved your problem, then select the check mark next to that answer to let others know what the correct answer is.  If an answer helped you but didn't necessarily solve your problem, select the up-arrow next to the answer to indicate that there is useful information in the answer.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your suggestion. I've been working with this over the last few days and I've now got this to work. Kind regards.